# How to retrieve dictionary values using split method?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Splitting dictionary not working in ansible.
Ansible- 2.5.15

Could anyone please help with any solution.

I was trying to fetch the values from dictionary but unable to fetch the values.

Tried code:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
       some_module: "{{ item.split(': ')[1] }}"
      with_items:
        - git: true
        - gradle: false
```

Getting below error:

```
The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'split'
```

Expected Results are like below:

[true, false]

Comment: I have used it couple of times, and it worked fine for me like this ```{{  ansible_nodename.split(".")[0] }}```

Answer (score 1):

You can handle it as a hashmap and get the key or the value:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
       some_module: "{{ item.values }}"
      with_items:
        - {git: true}
        - {gradle: false}
```

Comment: It gives below error.

MSG:

The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'value'

Answer (score 0):

<sup>(Updated for Ansible 2.9 and later)</sup>

Given the list

```yaml
    l:
      - git: true
      - gradle: false
```

the task

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        out: "{{ l|map('dict2items')|
                   flatten|
                   map(attribute='value')|
                   list }}"
```

gives the required result

```yaml
  out:
  - true
  - false
```

If the data were a dictionary, e.g.

```yaml
    d:
      git: true
      gradle: false
```

the solution would have been much simpler, e.g. the task below gives the same result

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        out: "{{ d.values()|list }}"
```

---

Notes

Your data is not a dictionary. It is a list

```
    - git: true
    - gradle: false
```

Dictionary is below

```
    git: true
    gradle: false
```

Let's create from the data a dictionary first and then use the [dict2items](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#dict-filter) filter.

The play below

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    data1:
      - {git: true}
      - {gradle: false}
    data2: {}
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        data2: "{{ data2|combine(item) }}"
      loop: "{{ data1 }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ data2|dict2items|json_query('[].value') }}"
```

gives:

```
"msg": [
    true, 
    false
]
```

*dict2items* is available since Ansible 2.6. In older versions use simple *filter_plugin* [hash_utils.py](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-plugins/blob/master/filter_plugins/hash_utils/hash_utils.py)

```
$ cat filter_plugins/hash_utils.py
def hash_to_tuples(h):
    return h.items()

def hash_keys(h):
    return h.keys()

def hash_values(h):
    return h.values()

class FilterModule(object):
    ''' utility filters for operating on hashes '''

    def filters(self):
        return {
            'hash_to_tuples' : hash_to_tuples
            ,'hash_keys'     : hash_keys
            ,'hash_values'   : hash_values
        }
```

The task below

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ data2|hash_values }}"
```

gives the same result as the construct with *dict2items* above. You might want to try other filters and review the details about *[filter_plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html#plugin-guidelines)*.

Comment: Hi,
dict2items filter supports in 2.6.
I have a server with installed ansible version of 2.5.15.
Could you please suggest any other filter.

Comment: @sushmitha i: You might want to use the *filter_plugin*. I've updated the answer.